# Detect Synchronous and Asynchronous Controller Actions in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, base-class

We recently ran into the issue where `ExecuteCore()` in BaseController was no longer being called. Worked in MVC 3 but not in MVC 4

So, I added the property  `protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport` to BaseController like so:

```
protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

The obvious problem now is what to do when we get an async action?
How can I detect if the controller action is synchronous VS asynchronous?

I need something like this, I think:

```
protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
{
    get
    {
        if(actionIsSynchronous)
            return true;
        else
            return false

    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Have you tried using BeginExecuteCore instead of ExecuteCore?

Comment: No, I have not. Please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **ExecuteCore** you can try to use **BeginExecuteCore**

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
}
```

Another solution could be to override the **Initialize** method.

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
      //Put your code here
}
```

Comment: If I implement that, I assume I no longer need this? base.ExecuteCore();

Comment: This should replace base.ExecuteCore(); and also DisableAsyncSupport